# Insert from file to chained list C

Tags: c

iam trying to read the data i saved in the file record.txt with the function and then read from file and insert the data into the linked list again but iam getting an infinite loop when I display the data from the list with i cant find the problem!

idk if the problem in the save function or the getfile function or the dispal i cant find any hint on my problem

Code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int import = 0 ;
struct Repertoire
{
    char phone[10];
    char name[100];
    char lastname[100];
    char adresse[100];
    char date[100];
    char email[100];

    struct Repertoire *next;

}* head;
void insert(char* phone, char* name, char* lastname, char* adresse, char* email, char* date)
{

    struct Repertoire * rep = (struct Repertoire *) malloc(sizeof(struct Repertoire));
    strcpy(rep->phone, phone);
    strcpy(rep->name, name);
    strcpy(rep->lastname, lastname);
    strcpy(rep->adresse, adresse);
    strcpy(rep->email, email);
    strcpy(rep->date, date);
    rep->next = NULL;

    if(head==NULL){
        // if head is NULL
        // set student as the new head
        head = rep;
    }
    else{
        // if list is not empty
        // insert student in beginning of head
        rep->next = head;
        head = rep;
    }

}

void display()
{
    struct Repertoire * temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL){

        printf("Phone Number: %s\n", temp->phone);
        printf("Name: %s\n", temp->name);
        printf("Lastname: %s\n", temp->lastname);
        printf("Adresse: %s\n", temp->adresse);
        printf("Date of birth: %s\n", temp->date);
        printf("email: %s\n", temp->email);
        temp = temp->next;


    }

}
void insertFile(){
struct Repertoire * temp = head;
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr=fopen("record.txt","a+");
    while(temp!=NULL){
        fprintf(ptr,"%s %s %s %s %s %s\n",temp->phone,temp->name,temp->lastname,temp->adresse,temp->date,temp->email);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    fclose(ptr);
}
void SaveFile(){
struct Repertoire * temp = head;
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr=fopen("new.txt","w");
    while(temp!=NULL){
        fprintf(ptr,"%s %s %s %s %s %s\n",temp->phone,temp->name,temp->lastname,temp->adresse,temp->date,temp->email);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
     fclose(ptr);
    remove("record.txt");
    rename("new.txt","record.txt");

}
void GetFile(){
char phone[10];
char name[100];
char lastname[100];
char adresse[100];
char date[100];
char email[100];
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr=fopen("record.txt","r");
    struct Repertoire * rep = (struct Repertoire *) malloc(sizeof(struct Repertoire));
    while(fscanf(ptr,"%s %s %s %s %s %s\n",phone,name,lastname,adresse,date,email)!=EOF){

            strcpy(rep->phone, phone);
            strcpy(rep->name, name);
            strcpy(rep->lastname, lastname);
            strcpy(rep->adresse, adresse);
            strcpy(rep->email, email);
            strcpy(rep->date, date);
            rep->next = NULL;

            if(head==NULL){
                // if head is NULL
                // set student as the new head
                head = rep;
            }
            else{
                // if list is not empty
                // insert student in beginning of head
                rep->next = head;
                head = rep;
            }


    }
    free(rep);
    printf("Data Ipmorted Successfully !!");
    import = 1 ;
fclose(ptr);
}
```

Comment: We get that you need help, you're here on Stack Overflow posting a question. There's no need to scream that in the title too. Please, calm down on the all-caps, the exclamation marks, and the 'asap' stuff.

Comment: `GetFile` reads into the same record over and over. Then you delete it. Not sure that does anything useful, especially since you keep a pointer to that deleted data. Remember `head = rep` copies **only pointer data**, it does not copy the record.

Comment: It's certainly worth stepping through this code in a debugger since you've dug yourself quite a hole here. There's a lot of things in this code that look suspicious at best, if not outright broken.

Comment: Don't cast the value returned by `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :

```
void GetFile(){
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr=fopen("record.txt","r");
    struct Repertoire * rep = (struct Repertoire *) malloc(sizeof(struct Repertoire));

while(!feof(ptr)){
        fscanf(ptr,"%s %s %s %s %s %s\n",rep->phone,rep->name,rep->lastname,rep->adresse,rep->date,rep->email);
            insert(rep->phone,rep->name,rep->lastname,rep->adresse,rep->date,rep->email);

}



    printf("Data Ipmorted Successfully !!\n");
    import = 1 ;
fclose(ptr);
}
```